# Why does dropping the last collection drop the database as well

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to delete a collection from database using script file (.js).

 My js file is a below

```
db1 = db.getSiblingDB('Books');
db1.TestBook.drop();
```

and executing like below

```
mongo localhost:27017 "d:/test.js"
```

When my database has multiple collection it is deleting that collection means "TestBook".

But if I try to deleted the last collection it is deleting the database as well.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does cause any problems?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlexBlex why it is deleting the database. My command is to delete collection only?

Comment: @D.SM it should not delete the database. Because my command it to delete collection not database.

Comment: Which command did you run to create the database at the first place?

Comment: @AlexBlex I have created through compass. The default tool for MongoDB.

Comment: Hmm, I was sure the default was the shell, but anyway. You didn't create database in compass, whatever UI was saying to you. There is no command to create or delete database. Please learn  https://www.mongodb.com/basics/create-database

Comment: @AlexBlex what does this statement means "You can create your MongoDB database, with either the mongo shell, or using Compass. Both methods are available for MongoDB Atlas clusters, and for self-managed clusters."

Comment: @AlexBlex  but there is no option to create only database. We need to create one collection at least. So What if I dropped the last collection and want to create the collection again. First I need to create the database and then collection?

Comment: @AlexBlex got the answer "To create a database you use the use command. If the database doesn’t exist, then the MongoDB cluster will create it."

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be how MongoDB works:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand({listDatabases:1})
{
    "databases" : [
        {
            "name" : "admin",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(8192),
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "config",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(12288),
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "local",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(8192),
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(8192),
            "empty" : false
        }
    ],
    "totalSize" : NumberLong(36864),
    "totalSizeMb" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 1
}
MongoDB Enterprise > db.foo.drop()
true
MongoDB Enterprise > db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand({listDatabases:1})
{
    "databases" : [
        {
            "name" : "admin",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(8192),
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "config",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(12288),
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "local",
            "sizeOnDisk" : NumberLong(8192),
            "empty" : false
        }
    ],
    "totalSize" : NumberLong(28672),
    "totalSizeMb" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 1
}
```

However, it appears that the database retains at least some of the configured state for the dropped database. For example, if you enable sharding on a database, then drop the last collection, then try to enable sharding on a new collection in that database, sharding on the collection will be enabled which requires the sharding to have already been enabled on the database.

Dropping collections does change the list of returned databases, which could be problematic for applications. You can report this as an issue via https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/server if you like.